# Fixed position div causes page to be truncated in less common mobile browsers

Tags: css, cross-browser, css-position, mobile-browser

I know there are many similar issues, but this is different to anything I have encountered before, so I thought I would describe the bug here, and offer a solution - and ask if anyone else has a better solution or can shed light on the cause of this weird issue.

The Bug:

In a page that has a div in position:fixed style, in some less common mobile browsers, e.g. Star Safari, DU Browser, Tint Browser - the page loads as expected, and the div is fixed as expected, however if the page height is greater than about 1500px, then the bottom of the page will be truncated - complete white curtain. You can still scroll to the bottom, but it's just white, zero content. 
 **This bug does NOT happen in more common browsers like chrome, firefox, opera, safari etc..**

Here's a screen shot from my phone (HTC M8 - Tint Browser) - also reproduced this bug on Samsung S5.

[image: Tint Browser Bug]

There are many reasons that you might want a fixed div, in my case it was for a menu button that can follow the viewport, so the visitor doesn't have to scroll back to the top to get the menu.

I have posted a semi-solution bellow, but I will not mark it correct for a week, so hopefully someone else can offer a better solution.

Tim

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason I call this a "semi-solution" for two reasons:

1) This will **not** keep the div perfectly fixed, but it will elegantly move the div after a scroll event.

2) While this doesn't cause the page to truncate permanently, it does flash the 'curtain' during the opacity transitions. Weird, right?

EDIT: I should mention that this solution looks great in the common browsers (chrom, safari etc...), the flashing curtain will only apply to browsers that would otherwise be truncated with the fixed position div, so although it isn't pretty in some less common browsers, it's still better than the alternative, and is a minor compromise in style for more the common browsers.

This is the code for the menu button example, adapt for your own needs.

HTML Example

```
<body onscroll="menuButton()">
    <div style="height:2000px; border: thick dotted green; width:90vw; background-color:#131313"></div>
    <div id="menuButton">
        <div class="image"></div>
    </div>
</body>
```

CSS

```
#menuButton {
    position: absolute;
    top:25px;
    left: 25px;
    opacity: 1;
    z-index: 1001;
    transition: opacity .4s ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition: opacity .4s ease-in-out;
    -webkit-transition: opacity .4s ease-in-out;
}

.image {
    width:50px;
    height:50px;
    background-color:red;
}
```

JavaScript

```
function menuButton() {
    setTimeout(function () {
        var button = document.getElementById("menuButton").style;
        var pos = document.documentElement.scrollTop || document.body.scrollTop;
        var newPos = pos + 25 + 'px'; // Offset is the start value of the div top position.
        button.opacity = 0;
        setTimeout(function () {
            button.top = newPos;
                    setTimeout(function () {
                        button.opacity = 1;
                    }, 500);
        }, 500);
    }, 800);
}
```

And here is a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/asimovwasright/yrndz4uz/5/)